# Python Jupyter Notebook: Put two histogram subplots side by side in one figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I am using Python (3.4) Jupyter Notebook. I have the following two histograms in two separated cells, each has their own figure:

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 40)
plt.hist(list1, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'r')
```

and

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 40)
plt.hist(list2, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'g')
```

Is it possible to put the above two histograms as two subplots side by side in one figure?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes this is possible. See the following code.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

list1 = np.random.rand(10)*2.1
list2 = np.random.rand(10)*3.
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].hist(list1, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'r')
ax[1].hist(list2, bins, alpha = 0.5, color = 'g')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with the expression for `bins`: `np.linspace(0, 1, 3)`?

Comment: @fraxture `bins` is the array that contains the edges of the bins for the histogram.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) for that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

list1 = np.random.rand(10)*2.1
list2 = np.random.rand(10)*3.0

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)  # 1 line, 2 rows, index nr 1 (first position in the subplot)
plt.hist(list1)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)  # 1 line, 2 rows, index nr 2 (second position in the subplot)
plt.hist(list2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's better practice to explain what you're doing.  For example, the arguments of `plt.subplot` aren't intuitive to the un-initiated and it is frequently nice to include your imports as well :-)

Comment: This is a solution to the question put by @Edamame to display two histograms as two subplots side by side in one figure.

Comment: @mgilson - Edamame was already using plt.hist. So, it was inherent that s/he had already imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt. Hencce the import was not included.

Comment: @Tanmoy -- Just because the asker and you know doesn't mean that future visitors to this question will know.  Remember, you're not just addressing Edamame's question -- You're also addressing the questions of future visitors who might be trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @mgilson: I updated the answer with working code (a bit taken from the other answer).This answer helped me so it could be useful for others too, as you mention.